# iOS SDK - Yahoo OAuth

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4, yahoo-api

I want to login my application through Yahoo. I have been following this tutorial: http://developer.yahoo.com/social/sdk/objectivec/ but it seems outdated.

In the following line the method `sendUserToAuthorizationWithCallback:` doesn't even exist:

```
[session sendUserToAuthorizationWithCallback:nil];
```

I changed this to:

```
[session sendUserToAuthorizationWithCallbackUrl:nil];
```

But I get a bad access exception inside Yahoo files. It didn't worked neither on iOS 4 nor on iOS 5.

The Yahoo sources are here: https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-objc

Comment: Hay mate Have you solved your problem?? is yes Can You please share the solution as I'm having same issue.

Comment: I did not solve it. I dropped support for Yahoo OAuth in my App.

Comment: Go through this link and follow the instructions given https://github.com/Swaroop1231/Yahoo-Authentication-Redirection-IOS

Answer (score 0):

it worked with me when i have assigned permissions to my app 
http://developer.apps.yahoo.com/projects/

Answer (score 0):

The above SDK should work now. Try it: https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-objc